# Use ENV variable in hook Cucumber

Tags: cucumber

How do I use an ENV variable in a hook?

I have some driver configs set in the my env.rb file that work on an if statement.

```
if ENV['headless_phantom']
  Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
    Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, window_size: [1280, 1024], js_errors: false, debug: false)
  end
  Capybara.default_driver = :poltergeist

elsif ENV['headless_chrome']
  Capybara.register_driver :headless_chrome do |app|

    opts = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
    opts.add_argument '--start-maximized'
    opts.add_argument '--disable-infobars'
    opts.add_argument '--headless'
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, options: opts)
  end
  Capybara.default_driver = :headless_chrome

...
```

Usually to invoke a driver other than the default, I add the following in the runner options in my IDE or command line:

```
headless_chrome = true
```

I'm looking to do the following to save me going into the runner options all the time to allow a quick change of driver when initially writing the tests.

```
before('@chrome_headless') do
  ENV['headless_chrome'] = true
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use cucumber profiles and then set the ENV var there. See https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/cucumber.yml for details on how to use profiles.

Keep It Super Simple! Otherwise it will grow into a nightmare to maintain.